# Cauchy's integral formula with a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Can Cauchy's integral formula be used when $f(z)$ is equal to a constant? For example, in $\int {dz \over {z-a}}$ could I say that $f(z)=1$?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  That's right.  If $\oint_C \frac{f(z)\, dz}{z-a}  = \oint_C \frac{dz}{z-a}$, then  $f(z)=1.$